HiGHS not available in pyomo
I'm trying to use HiGHS in pyomo, but the solver remains unavalable. Pyomo v6.8.2, HiGHS v1.8.1, both properly installed and well behaving individually. I also already tried using the executable argument to pyo.SolverFactory: No complaints that the executable would not exist. Still the solver remains unavailable.
An MWE is:
import pyomo.environ as pyo
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.x = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.y = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.con = pyo.Constraint(expr = model.x + model.y <= 10)
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr= model.x + model.y)
optimizer = pyo.SolverFactory('highs', executable='C:/HiGHS-1.8.1/build/bin/Release/highs')
print("HiGHS availability is ", optimizer.available())
optimizer.solve(model)

which gives output:
HiGHS availability is  False
ERROR: Solver (asl) returned non-zero return code (4294967295)
ERROR: Solver log: ERROR:   Error parsing options: Option 'A' does not exist

line 628, in solve
    raise ApplicationError("Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name)
pyomo.common.errors.ApplicationError: Solver (asl) did not exit normally

The issue appears both on my local Windows machine and on a virtual Azure VM running Linux. Are there any incompatibilities between pyomo and HiGHS that I am not aware of?

The HiGHS interface was developed for APPSI (and not the older "legacy" (standard) SolverFactory[*1]).  You can get a compatible wrapper around it through the legacy solver factory with:
solver = SolverFactory("appsi_highs")

*1:  Pyomo is in the process of redesigning the core standard solver interfaces to make them more consistent and easier to develop, maintain, and extend.  APPSI (the Autopersistent Pyomo Solver Interface) included an initial draft of a new interface, and is being used as the template for the new standard interface under development).
